# Implementing OAuth in MVC - I want to stop execution after a Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm implementing an OAuth solution, where I provide an endpoint to an external system that needs to contact my application.

The system initially calls this endpoint (an MVC action method), and I then need to do a Response.Redirect to send the user back to the original system.

I need to stop my code execution immediately after the Response.Redirect is called. I've tried the following, which don't stop the code execution:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url, true);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

I also tried returning an ActionResult after the redirect however this causes an error that I think is related to the fact that I'm trying to redirect and then return a result as a response.

How can I stop the code executing after the Response.Redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(...)`, you'll want to use the controller's own `Redirect(...)` method:

```
return Redirect(url);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not doing the redirect in the controller though, I'm doing it in a standard C# class that the controller uses. I think that the kind of redirect you're suggesting is of type 'RedirectResult', and it doesn't seem to be available to me in the C# class. Can I return Redirect(url) from a C# class that's outside the controller? If so, how?

Comment: You could instantiate a `System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult` (found in System.Web.Mvc.dll in case you happen to be off in a different project), but that's not going to magically stop your controller from evaluating other stuff after this.  If you're at all able to modify the calling controller, you're going to want to have it be able return the Redirect action (or other ActionResults) from your other method it calls.